# Why has my wood panelling in my shed expanded and popped out? How can I fix it?

Tags: wood, shed, water-damage, paneling

Last summer we bought a shed and panelled inside with tongue and groove panelling. We put up damp proof and insulation first and then the panels on top. We used panel pins on every third board.
Over the winter it seems the wood has expanded causing it to push out in places. How can we fix this and can we prevent it happening again?

Comment: Any pics to show the extent?

Comment: Is the space temperature controlled?

Comment: Sounds  like moisture trapped in the insulation.

Comment: That's very odd. Wood usually _contracts_ in winter. Is "winter" where you are actually warm, but humid?

Comment: To add pics, click the [edit] link, then simply drag & drop the pics into your post. The site will upload & host them for you. If you can't do that, post them to imgur.com or similar and paste the links in the comments, someone will embed them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your shed may have shifted. I have a larger shed that had this wood veneer nailed to the walls, and it's shifted somewhat, which warps the paneling.

I would make sure your footings and walls are still level. If they aren't, you can use a car jack (use a car stand for a safety backstop) to raise the shed and add supports to raise it back to level.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I’m in Northern Ireland, so our winters are wet and around -3C to 12C. Could have made it damp inside shed. We stapled black damp proof to the shed walls and then packed the space with insulation that came in a thick roll before panelling. Is that the correct order? I can’t seem to add a photo. It is worse around the door and window. We haven’t got any hearing in the shed. If we can fix it we will air it out more often and use a space heater occasionally on it throughout winter. Would this help? Do you think the wood will shrink again as the weather warms?